# Android - Activity to Fragment exchange - ListAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I would like to change my Activity to Fragment, but I have problem with this:

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                BusTimetableActivity.this, departuresList,
                R.layout.bus_timetable_layout, new String[] { TAG_TYPE,
                TAG_HOUR }, new int[] { R.id.type, R.id.hour });

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

How can I exchange this part:

```
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                BusTimetableActivity.this, departuresList,
                R.layout.bus_timetable_layout, new String[] { TAG_TYPE,
                TAG_HOUR }, new int[] { R.id.type, R.id.hour });

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Because it works well on Activity, but when I exchange Activity to Fragment it doesn't work. How I can exchange this part to Fragment?

Comment: `but I have small problem with this method` which small problem? and what you mean by `How can I exchange part with ListAdapter?` ?

Comment: I change my Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because creating `SimpleAdapter` Adapter object from Fragment,so pass `getActivity()` instead of `BusTimetableActivity.this` as first paramter to `SimpleAdapter` constructor

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
        getActivity(), departuresList,
          R.layout.bus_timetable_layout, new String[] { TAG_TYPE,
                TAG_HOUR }, new int[] { R.id.type, R.id.hour });
```

And also extend `ListFragment` instead of `Fragment` to call:

`setListAdapter(adapter);`